# add number to strings in data frame

Tags: r

How do I assign numbers to a string in a data frame like below?

I tried something like this, but its not correct: `row.names(d) <- paste(d[,1],1:96,sep="")`

```
> head(d,10)
   condition
1          T
2          N
3          T
4          N
5          T
6          N
7          T
8          N
9          T
10         N
```

output:

```
   condition
T1          T
N1          N
T2          T
N2          N
T3          T
N3          N
T4          T
N4          N
T5          T
N5          N
```

Comment: Many many possible ways. With base R it could be `with(d, ave(as.character(condition), condition, FUN = function(x) paste0(x, seq(length(x)))))`. With "data.table": `library(data.table) ; setDT(d)[, res := paste0(condition, seq_len(.N)), by = condition]`, with "dplyr": `library(dplyr) ; d %>% group_by(condition) %>% mutate(res = paste0(condition, row_number()))` and so on and on...

Answer (score 3):

Using row names is generally a bad practice because they become meaningless the moment you start manipulating the data. Nevertheless, you could achieve your desired output using

```
row.names(d) <- with(d, ave(as.character(condition), condition, FUN = function(x) paste0(x, seq(length(x)))))
d
#    condition
# T1         T
# N1         N
# T2         T
# N2         N
# T3         T
# N3         N
# T4         T
# N4         N
# T5         T
# N5         N
```

Though I'd recommend something like

```
d$res <- with(d, ave(as.character(condition), condition, FUN = function(x) paste0(x, seq(length(x)))))
```

Some other alternatives could be

```
library(data.table) 
setDT(d)[, res := paste0(condition, seq_len(.N)), by = condition]
```

Or (don't run this on a `data.table` object)

```
library(dplyr)  
library(magrittr)
d %<>% 
  group_by(condition) %>% 
  mutate(res = paste0(condition, row_number()))
```

There could be some options which I'll leave to other people to figure out.